# Looking for short value in C++ Array fast SIMD version

Tags: c++, simd

I have an algorithm in my program which works fine. I speculate if there is possible to speed think up a little bit:

```
unsigned short c;   
bool found = false;
unsigned short* arrIterator = arr;
while(( c = *arrIterator & mask) != stopValue)
{       
    if(c == next)
    {               
        found= true;
        break;                  
    }
    arrIterator ++;
}
```

It is possible to rewrite such algorithm to SIMD instructions?

Comment: Can you configure the compiler for high optimization level first?  You should then print out the assembly language to see if the compiler generated SIMD instructions.

Comment: Also, try using array notation rather than pointer.  Usually, pointers only point to a single value.  An array indicates there are more than one value and the values are contiguous.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the aligned 16-byte block containing the stop value does not have a value equal to `next` *after* the stop value?

Comment: Yes, I can add several stop values to solve this issue.

Comment: I checked the ASM and compiler does not generate SIMD for high optimization level. How can be compiler sure that the array is properly aligned? That the stop value is there several times? Or can I help a tell to the compiler that the array is always aligned and that the value cannot be found after stop value? I suppose I need to write this code manually as example bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `arr` is 16-aligned (make it so), you could do something like this (not tested)

```
__m128i vstop = _mm_set1_epi16(stopValue);
__m128i vnext = _mm_set1_epi16(next);
int found_mask = 0;
int stop_mask = 0;
do
{
    __m128i data = _mm_load_si128(arrIterator++);
    __m128i contains_next = _mm_cmpeq_epi16(data, vnext);
    __m128i contains_stop = _mm_cmpeq_epi16(data, vstop);
    found_mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(contains_next);
    stopmask = found_mask | _mm_movemask_epi8(contains_stop);
} while (stopmask == 0);
```

You can then tell the index where `next` was found by doing a bitscan over `found_mask` and some stuff with the current value of the iterator.